# Erro inexplicável descoberto após ter a questão "solucionada"

Tags: suporte

Minha dúvida é sobre esta pergunta: [Como escolher o maior valor de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59407/como-escolher-o-maior-valor-de-um-array/59503?noredirect=1)

O que acontece é que após acreditar ter descoberto o que era o problema, o problema na verdade não era este, e na verdade o código que está na pergunta está correto.

Eu realmente não tenho ideia do que aconteceu. Só descobri que o problema não era aquele por que o Guilherme explicou que não tinha mesmo diferença usar aspas duplas ou simples neste caso, daí fui fazer o teste e WTF... Eu achei ter lembrado de ter ouvido isso (que o que está entre aspas duplas é sempre string, e que isso podia fazer diferença) mas acho que viajei na maionese,  pensei que a solução foi por que mudei as aspas, mas devo ter mudado alguma outra coisa. Não sei mesmo, foi mal...

Acho que a pergunta pode até ser útil pra alguém, mas na verdade foi uma pergunta incabível, porque o código que apresentei funciona do jeito que está, e não funciona com o que achei que fosse a solução (incluir o `(double)`, ou com minha "genial" solução das aspas simples).

O que faço agora, apago a pergunta? Mas vai dar uma dó! :)

PS: Já tirei o sinal de solucionado da resposta. Shame on me.

Comment: Gustavo acho que não é necessário fechar ou deletar, já que as respostas apresentaram bons exemplos no código. A resposta do @PapaCharlie é um bom exemplo para trabalhar com arrays.

Comment: Sim, eu também acho  (talvez editar a pergunta pra explicar o que ocorreu né), mas como sou novato achei melhor fazer a pergunta aqui. Valeu.

Comment: Tranquilo, você está indo muito bem, até melhor que muitos novatos.

Comment: Valeu cara, o SOpt tem me ajudado tanto que o mínimo que posso fazer é perguntar direito. Li acho que praticamente tudo da ajuda, e várias perguntas relacionadas, algumas geniais como a da luta entre o Gorila e Tubarão :-), e isso ajudou bastante a entender o que a comunidade espera de quem faz as perguntas.